# Transfer Learning for Vanilla Neural Network

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch, neural-network

Is it possible to do transfer learning for vanilla neural network?

I meant vanilla neural network as classic classification prediction such as whether the transaction is a fraud, the employee may quit the job, etc.

I have a trained neural network model which I would like to freeze and train the last few layers on different similar domain dataset. Is this possible?

I could not find any reference on google for transfer learning of Vanilla neural network.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Transfer learning refers to the process of using a neural network already specialized on one task, and reused some of his layers on another close task.

For instance, a large language model learns a lot about language, so you freeze his layers and add on top of it new layers, for instance you want to classify emotions, so you add this layers on top of the previous one and you train them. (previous layers are frozen, new ones aren't)

So for vanilla network it's totally possible. You do the same process of removing the layers you don't want and add new speciliazed layers on top of it (aka classification layers for instance)

Without code it's hard to give you a better answer, feel free to ask in comments